# SELECT * FROM and mysqli_fetch_array using Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

After a long time avoiding Prepared Statements I want to leave my comfort zone and update all my sites to mysqli, but I'm having a really hard time to achieve things that seem simple before...

Connection

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

All my query's were built this way:

```
$id = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Then I could print all needed fields:

```
Name: $row['name'];
Email: $row['email'];
Address: $row['address'];
City: $row['city'];
...
```

I've tried several ways to `prepare`, `execute`, `bind` and `fetch` the results in a simple way, or similar to what I was used to, but none of them work for me.

My statement is that bad? I mean, if I sanitize all itens before any `Query` or `Insert` my statement will remain insecure?

Can anyone show me a example of how can I use prepared statement but still be able to print my results individually, like: $row['name], $row['address'], $row['city']...

**JUST TO UPDATE A FEW THINGS**

This code works properly, my connection is ok and the $id is declared above my query (I've edited my question). My question is how can I "transform" this code into a **mySQLi Prepared Statement** and still be able to print results individually like $row['name'], $row['address']...

Comment: What errors you are getting? Are you able to connect to database?

Comment: @Anshum I'm not getting any errors, this code works perfectly, I've updated my question with the missing info (database and id declaration). My question is how can I transform this code into a mysqli prepared statement and still be able to print results individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$id =1;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, email from users where id=?")) {

  /* bind parameters for markers */
  $stmt->bind_param("d", $id);

  /* execute query */
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->bind_result($name, $email);

  /* fetch value */
  $stmt->fetch();

  printf("%s has email %s", $name, $email);
  /* close statement */
  $stmt->close();
}

?>
```

May it help

Comment: I've updated my question, the code is working ok. My question is how to transform this statement into a mysqli prepared statement, to prevent injections and speeds up query execution.